# What happens when you pass a NSMutable* object to a method accepting a NS* object?

Tags: c++, objective-c, constants, parameter-passing, immutability

I am just starting out with Objective-C, and I have a question about a functionality. 
Suppose that I have a method accepting and storing a `NSDictionary` object, and i provide it with a `NSMutableDictionary` (which is, after all, a `NSDictionary`). This method stores it inside the object, in a `NSDictionary` property, so the type of the object becomes in fact `NSDictionary`. This means that the selectors for adding objects to the NSMutableDictionary are not there anymore.

I come from a C++ background and, while I should try not to map Objective-C practices on C++ practices, this looks very similar to how the `const`ness is handled in C++ (i.e., if you pass a non-`const` to a method accepting a `const` variant of the same type, the object becomes `const` inside the method (and thus the instance) scope.

Could someone enlighten me on this?

Thanks,
Tommaso

Comment: Total protonic reversal.

Comment: (Don't think in terms of C++ `const`, consider NSMutableX to be a subclass of NSX.  You can pass an NSMutableX to a method expecting an NSX, but not vice-versa, and no playing with casts, etc, will change that.)

Comment: (In practice, NSX and NSMutableX are members of a "class cluster" and not in a strict class hierarchy, but an internal flag enforces the mutable/immutable distinction, regardless of how you might cast things or manipulate pointers.)

Answer (score 1):

This part of your question:

> This method stores it inside the object, in a `NSDictionary` property, so the type of the object becomes in fact `NSDictionary`.

... is false. No type conversion occurs. The object remains an `NSMutableDictionary`, it's just no longer explicit from the interface that it is so.

Objective-C objects are untyped at runtime. Typing is for your benefit as a programmer and allows the compiler to generate appropriate warnings. Casting a pointer has exactly the same effect as casting a pointer in C++ — it makes no difference to the thing being pointed to. In this case all you're doing is casting a pointer to a mutable thing to a pointer to the immutable thing (which is a superclass, as far as the compiler cares, so the cast is allowed to be implicit).

If you want to take an immutable copy of a mutable object, use `copy`. `copy` always returns an immutable copy, with `mutableCopy` being required for a mutable copy even if the original was mutable. Declare the property with the `copy` modifier to have the former done for you. Don't worry about unnecessary copying of objects that were already immutable — they'll return themselves as the copy (with appropriate memory ownership bookkeeping performed).

Comment: Is it possible to make a mutable object immutable by just flipping a bit, without actually copying the whole thing?

Comment: No, it's not, at least by official API. Such a thing would be a design flaw. If objects A and B both have ownership of mutable array N, then B flips N to immutable then A is left in an invalid state.